# What's the (short) type of `10 *~ (watt / second)`

Tags: haskell, dimensional

Quick question: Using [dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional) GHC infers the type of `testRate = 10 *~ (watt / second)` to be:

```
testRate
  :: Numeric.Units.Dimensional.Quantity
       (Numeric.Units.Dimensional.Dim
          (numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Pos
             numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Pos1)
          (numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Pos
             numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Zero)
          (numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Neg
             (numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Neg
                numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Neg2))
          numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Zero
          numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Zero
          numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Zero
          numtype-1.0.1:Numeric.NumType.Zero)
       a
```

What would be the *short* type of testRate? And how do I derive the type of other such units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch to [dimensional-tf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-tf) you can write it as

```
testRate :: Quantity (Div DPower DTime) a
```

I don't think there's a good generic way to derive these types, just write down the type equivalent of what you think the unit should be (using `Mul` and `Div`).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the short type? The best you could do would be to remove all the module qualifiers, eg

```
testRate
  :: Quantity
       (Dim
          (Pos Pos1)
          (Pos Zero)
          (Neg (Neg Neg2))
          Zero
          Zero
          Zero
          Zero)
       a
```

Comment: By "short" I mean something that makes obvious that we are dealing with `power over time` here. I could of course define `type powerOverTime :: Quantity (Dim ...` but I hope there is a better way.